# Simple inverting op amp not working

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm trying to amplify an electret microphone signal with an inverting op amp (LM358). I don't have access to an oscilloscope at the moment but with a voltmeter I read around 12mV at V1 and around 12mV as well at V2. For testing I am just playing a 1kHz test tone by the mic. Does this mean my op amp is not actually amplifying the signal. If my gain is -100 currently, then I should be getting 1.2V at the output of the op amp correct?

On a side note, if the microphone is outputting a varying voltage centered at 0, shouldn't the voltmeter give me 0V? What is measured by the voltmeter, is it peak to peak? Average? Also I am a first year EE student so please take into account my limited technical knowledge.

Yes the ground rails on the left and right are connected (not shown in pic)

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: See https://breadboardtronics.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/lm358-microhone-preamp-tutorial/ on biasing.

Comment: You need +/- supplies to have the output go below (about) zero volts. Also make sure you have the polarity of the microphone capsule correct.

Comment: Yes microphone polarity is correct.

Comment: Bias the non-inverting input up to mid-supply using two 10k resistors in series between the voltage rail and 0 v and then add a 10uF capacitor from the mid-supply bias voltage to 0 V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the voltage supposed to come from that ever could get the "-" input below the "+" input?  You either need a -9V supply for the opamp, or you need to put its "+" pin on a higher operating point, like using a voltage divider (2×4.7k, for example) and a smoothing capacitor (22µF, say) to arrive at 4.5V.  Of course, if you do that, you will have this as DC on the output and will want an output capacitor for removing it, too.

Comment: Your first sentence asks a valid question. I suggest that rewording it as a statement of what is required would be more helpful when addressing a beginner.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I figured to do something like that. I added a voltage divider (2 10K resistors) and I have half of supply going into the + input. I have a 10uF cap going from the + input to ground. Lastly I added a 0.1uF capacitor between the output of the op amp to V2. The issue is now I am getting 0V at V2 and half of supply voltage at V1.

Comment: another thing I notice is that when I test the microphone circuit alone (ie removing everything to the right of V1 and probing V1), I get a voltage that drops (I am assuming something to do with the cap) slowly until it gets to about 2mV where it hovers around there regardless of whether I play a sound or not. Can somebody explain what is going on here I am so lost.

Comment: @HiThere "The issue is now I am getting 0V at V2 and half of supply voltage at V1."  How is that an issue?  That's the correct DC bias at V1 and an output idle voltage of 0V (admittedly, you actually need some load to get the output capacitor the proper DC charge, so you could add a 22k resistor to ground there if you have no other load).  That's exactly what you should be seeing.

Comment: @user107063 Could you see if I am understanding this correct: is V2 zero (I tried with a load resistor it was 0V as expected) because the signal is centered at 0V and the voltmeter is simply reading the average voltage which is 0V? And at V1 it is reading 4.5V but really it is a very small signal from the microphone centered at 4.5V?

Comment: @HiThere That is exactly what you are supposed to be measuring and seeing.  For checking that anything happens, you should connect some sort of amplifier (watch out for feedback howl, turn up slowly while tapping the mic).

Comment: @user107063 Ok that helps a lot. I still have one lingering question: In my original schematic, which only amplifies half of the wave, shouldn't V2 still output some sort of amplified signal? Why is it outputting the same voltage coming from the mic?

Comment: @HiThere It isn't.  The "voltage coming from the mic" is blocked with the 1µF capacitor.  What you get instead is the lowest voltage the output circuit of the opamp can manage (the LM358 includes 0V in its common mode input range so it "knows" it should be pulling its output down further but cannot deliver).

Answer (score 0):

The signal generated by the mic and 2.2k bias resistor will have a DC offset that you decouple with the 1uF capacitor. Because of this decoupling, you have an (ideally) pure AC signal, meaning the voltage can go above and below 0V (negative and positive voltage).

You are powering the op amp with a single supply (9V battery), meaning you are only amplifying half your signal, the positive half.

To solve this without using a dual (+9V and -9V) supply, you need to add a DC bias to your signal (setting a reference voltage, Vref) at the non-inverting (+) pin of your op amp, and then use the circuit below. Note: Vref is usually half the supply voltage, so 4.5V if your supply is 9V. This gives you the full amplitude range of the op amp in single supply operation.

In this case, you want to calculate `b` to be 4.5V while also getting the amplification you want of `m = 100`. The math is simple and the document linked below shows you how to do the calculations.

[image]

[image]

The source of the screenshots and more on the topic of single supply operation of op amps [can be found here](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa030a/sloa030a.pdf).